# how to check String value index in NSMutableArray

Tags: nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray, indexof

```
NSMutableArray *arr_Status =[@"Pending",@"In Progress",@"In Testing",@"Needs Research",@"Limitation",@"Issue Not Clear",@"Unassigned"];
```

I am Having one `NSString *String = @"Limitation"`

how to get index String Value in NSMutableArray

Comment: `NSInteger index = [arr_Status indexOfObject:String];`?